# bash (replacing values in a column with values in another file)

Tags: bash, sed

Trying to make a file that has UID/GID of each directory and files.

"`out`" includes all the directories/files with username and group names.

And I want to compare this to column `$1` of /etc/passwd and replace it with uid/gid listed in `/etc/passwd`

so let's say "`out`" includes"

```
sam samgroup /home/sam/hi
aaron samgroup /home/aaron/no
```

I want it to become

```
1001 1002 /home/sam/hi
1002 1002 /home/aaron/no
```

(after comparing to columns and replacing/appending from `/etc/passwd`).

I wrote this but is this logically correct? and if not, how do fix it?
Thank you.

[UPDATED]

```
one="$(awk -F ":" '{print $2}' out)"
psw="$(awk -F ":" '{print $1}' /etc/passwd)"
pswthree="$(awk -F ":" '{print $3}' /etc/passwd)"
pswfour="$(awk -F ":" '{print $4}' /etc/passwd)"


while read -r out
do
        if  [ $one == $two ]
                then sed "s/$one/$pswthree/g" <<< "$out"
        fi
done < out
```

sample /etc/passwd

```
nfsnobody:x:65534:65534:Anonymous NFS User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin
qemu:x:107:107:qemu user:/:/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: few errors: you read into variable out but are not using the value - you should use `$out` in the body of `while`. You are not really running `awk`, you want something like `$(awk ...)`. But you first need to search for the matching line in /etc/passwd and I dont see you doing that. And after `if` you need `then` and `fi`, not `do`.

Comment: There are some syntax errors.  That should probably be while read -r line and   you should have done < out, not match. The 'if' is missing a corresponding 'then' and there are a few semicolons missing. I would work on this incrementally if I were you. First get the syntax right so your code runs, and then improve it little by little.

Comment: I would start by making sure you can iterate over the lines in the file and print them out. `while read -r line
do
 echo $line
done < out`
From there add an if. and get that right. Then play around with awk.

Comment: you should be able to do this all i n1 awk script (if I understand your sample output correctly). See http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html for a reasonable tutorial. Good luck.

Comment: AND `awk -F ":" '{print $2}' out == awk -F ":" '{print $1}'` looks particularly wrong. Run your code thru http://shellcheck.net and update your Q with your best attempt at removing all errors flagged. Good luck.

Comment: Looks like you aren't comfortable with awk, bash or sed. If you know python and really need this result you might be able to whip up a python script pretty quickly to do this.

Comment: thanks. used a shellcheck to arrive at updated question. hmm but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

I think this is what you want to do

```
$ awk -F: 'NR==FNR  {a[$1]=$3 OFS $4; next}   # cache /etc/passwd user/groupids
           $1 in a  {print a[$1], $3; next}   # if found replace
           1' /etc/passwd FS=' +' out         # otherwise print as is
```

no explicit loops necessary

Note: id fields should be 3 and 4 in the password file.

Comment: the output yields nothing so i'm looking into modifying my question

Comment: are you searching with groupnames or usernames?  your out file seems "user group dir" format, but you're using second field. Can you post a sample section of the /etc/passwd file?

Comment: i've put a sample "/etc/passwd" thanks a lot for your time. I'm trying to debug my "if" statement at the same time.

Comment: the script should work, however currently there are no matching entries.  Also you out file is not colon delimited.  You should be using first field not second.  Change "sam" to "qemu" in your out file and try my script.

Comment: ah I see. I'll delimit colon and there shall be space to take your script. thanks again

Comment: i decided to go with my original attempt and please look at updated question when you have time

Comment: Well, I tried to help but you're not getting. Your code cannot work as is. You're trying to iterate on two files by willpower. "two" in undefined. etc. Good luck!

Comment: I'll study up more and ask better questions next time. Thank you so far for your time